# Laravel sort items by column relation?

Tags: php, laravel, sql-order-by

I would like to sort items by column relation in laravel (5.1)

I have a database table called interests, with a column called 'town_searched' and I would like to sort interests by town_searched in my view

When I have all interests, How can I order by town_searched ?

Example of the result I want in my view :

In the town of Sydney :

- Interest
- Interest

In the town of New-York

- Interest
- Interest

**My controller :**

```
     $userid = \Auth::id();
     $interests = DB::table('interests')
                    ->where('user_id', $userid)
                    ->groupBy('town_searched')
                    ->get();
```

Thanks for your help ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean `orderBy('town_searched', 'ASC')`?

```
$userid = \Auth::id();
$interests = DB::table('interests')
                ->where('user_id', $userid)
                ->groupBy('town_searched')
                ->orderBy('town_searched', 'ASC')
                ->get();
```

Comment: In my view, I want to have interests sort by town_searched but I don't know how to do that :/ Not have all interests directly, but by town

Comment: Did you try my example?

Comment: Yeah i've update my controller with your proposition, but I don't know how to show this in my view with distinction between each town_searched